# multiprocessing - blanket process termination

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, robotics, terminate, kill-process

I'm building a GUI to control a robot in Python.
The GUI has a few buttons, each one executes a function that loops indefinitely.
It's like a roomba, where the "clean kitchen" function makes it continually clean until interrupted.

In order to keep the GUI interactive, I'm executing the function in a separate process using multiprocessing.

I've got a stop function that I call that returns the robot to home, and kills the child process (otherwise the child process would reach the next line, and the robot would start turning around when it's left the kitchen and gone home). The stop function runs in the main/parent process as it doesn't loop.

I've got a GUI button which calls Stop, and I'll also call it whenever I start a new process.

My processes are started like this:

```
from file1 import kitchen
from file2 import bedroom

    if event == "Clean kitchen":
       stoptour()
       p = multiprocessing.Process(target=kitchen,args=(s,),daemon=True)
       p.start()

    if event == "Clean bedroom":
       stoptour()
       p = multiprocessing.Process(target=bedroom,args=(s,),daemon=True)
       p.start()
```

The argument being passed is just the socket that the script is using to connect to the robot.
My stop function is:

```
def stoptour():
   p.terminate()
   p.kill()
   s.send(bytes.fromhex(XXXX)) #command to send the stop signal to the robot
   p.join()
```

This all runs without error and the robot stops, but then starts up again (because the child process is still running). I confirmed this by adding to the stop function:

```
if p.is_alive:
        print('Error, still not dead')
    else:
        print('Success, its dead')
```

Every time it prints "Error, still not dead"...
Why are p.kill and p.terminate not working? Is something spawning more child processes?
Is there a way to write my `stoptour()` function so that it kills any and all child processes completely indiscriminately?

---

Edited to show the code:

```
import socket
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import multiprocessing
import time

from file1 import room1
from file2 import room2
from file3 import room3

#Define the GUI window
layout = [[sg.Button("Room 1")],
          [sg.Text("Start cleaning of room1")],
          [sg.Button("Room 2")],
          [sg.Text("Start cleaning of room2")],
          [sg.Button("Room 3")],
          [sg.Text("Start cleaning room3")],
          [sg.Button("Stop")],
          [sg.Text("Stop what you're doing")]]

# Create the window
window = sg.Window("Robot Utility", layout)

#Setup TCP Connection & Connect
TCP_IP = '192.168.1.100' #IP
TCP_port = 2222 #Port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #Setup TCP connection
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_port)) #Connect

#Define p so I can define stop function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=room1, args=(s,), daemon=True)
    p.start()
    p.terminate()
    p.kill()
    p.join()

#Define stop function
def stoptour():
    s.send(bytes.fromhex('longhexkey'))
    p.terminate()
    p.kill()
    p.join()
    s.send(bytes.fromhex('longhexkey')) #No harm stopping twice...
    if p.is_alive:
        print('Error, still not dead')
    else:
        print('Success, its dead')
stoptour()

#GUI event loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Room 1":
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            stoptour()
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=room1, args=(s,), daemon=True)
            p.start()

        
    if event == "Room 2":
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            stoptour()
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=room2, args=(s,), daemon=True)
            p.start()

    if event == "Room 3":
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            stoptour()
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=room3, args=(s,), daemon=True)
            p.start()
        
    if event == "Stop":
        stoptour()
        sg.popup("Tour stopped")
    
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        stoptour()
        s.close()
        print('Closing Program')
        break

window.close()
```

Comment: that's hard to tell without seeing the code for the global stop & the main loop

Comment: Note `p.kill` doesn't call `kill`, you need to do `p.kill()`

Comment: Sorry, p.kill was a typo - the script does use p.kill()

Comment: Edited so full script is shown at the bottom.